# Alinear una texto a la izquierda y otro a la derecha en itext 7

Tags: android, itext

Buen día, actualmente estoy enfrentando un problema de alineación de texto con **itext 7** verán yo estoy creando una especia de factura con texto y montos pero actualmente he logrado que todo el párrafo se alinee en una sola dirección ya sea izquierda o derecha como lo ven en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven todo el texto esta a la derecha pero necesito separarlo necesito que el texto este a la izquierda y los montos a la derecha siempre en la misma linea claro, así como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he logrado hacer esto con **itext 7**, esta es el código para crear los párrafo:

```
detalle = "[C]" + gTipoPago + "\n" +
                                    "[R]================================\n" +
                                    "[L]" + "Venta(+) $           " + String.format("%.2f", monto) + "\n" +
                                    "[R]" + "Devolución(-) $          " + String.format("%.2f", montoDevolucion) + "\n" +
                                    "[R]" + "Encontrado(-) $            " + String.format("%.2f", montoFisico) + "\n" +
                                    "[R]" + "Monto diferencia(=) $        " + String.format("%.2f", montoDiferencia) + "\n" +
                                    "[R]================================\n";

                            arrayList.add(detalle);
```

Como son datos de la base de datos dinámicos pues hago una consulta y los agrego a un `arraylist` y quizá ese sea el problema que los datos sean dinámicos o no se...

Luego en **itext 7** creo el párrafo y mando a llamar a ese `arraylist`:

```
Paragraph gastos = new Paragraph(arrayList2.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "") + "\n").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
```

En este caso como ven **itext 7** nada mas de la la opción de alinear a la izquierda a la derecha o al centro y como en un arreglo el que obtengo pues todo el arreglo se me alinea a la posición que le doy en este caso `TextAlignment.LEFT`

En conclusión busco una forma de separar el texto de las cantidades para alinearlos en la posición que desee siempre en la misma linea claro.

Y pues eso seria todo si necesitan mas explicación o mas código o lo que sea háganmelo saber de antemano muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero usar una tabla para agregar los textos a la izquierda y los precios a la derecha de esta forma:

```
Table table = new Table(3);    
table.addCell(getCell("Venta(+)", TextAlignment.LEFT));    
table.addCell(getCell("", TextAlignment.CENTER));    
table.addCell(getCell(String.format("%.2f", monto), TextAlignment.RIGHT));    
doc.add(table);

table = new Table(3);   
table.addCell(getCell("Devolución(-)", TextAlignment.LEFT));    
table.addCell(getCell("", TextAlignment.CENTER));    
table.addCell(getCell(String.format("%.2f", montoDevolucion), TextAlignment.RIGHT));    
doc.add(table);
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias la verdad esto me ayudo mucho me encontraba con el problema que no quería se que vieran los bordes pero solo le agrego la propiedad setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER) a la tabla y ya se mira como en la segunda imagen, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

ElementoItext elemento = new ElementoItext ();
elemento.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

//Tu decides donde se alinea

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente qué hace este código, además de darle formato. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.